# error - : incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short

Tags: java, exception

I know this error occurs when we try downcasting values but in my code I am not able to figure ooout where have I downcasted the values.

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        TestDemo obj=new TestDemo();
        TestDemo2 obj1= new TestDemo2();
        obj.show(5);
        obj1.show("helloworld");
    }
}
class TestDemo{
    public void show(short N){
        System.out.println(N*2);
    }  
}
class TestDemo2{
    public Void show(String S){
        System.out.println(S);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add a stacktrace to that?

Comment: @Buzzet OP can't do that, as the problem is a compiler error, not a runtime error.

Comment: Style question - is there any reason to declare the parameter to 'show' as 'short' rather than 'int'?  It seems over-specific in this example.

Comment: 'int' would have worked here but since the value for N can be limited within the ;limits of 'short' so I tried with short which gave the error

Answer (score 3):

This error is occurring due to obj.show(5).

Two fixes`you can do any:

```
    class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        TestDemo obj=new TestDemo();
        TestDemo2 obj1= new TestDemo2();
        obj.show((short)5);
        obj1.show("helloworld");
    }
}
class TestDemo{
    public void show(short i){
        
        System.out.println(i*2);
    }  
}
class TestDemo2{
    public void show(String S){
        System.out.println(S);
    }
}
```

Second Version

```
    class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        TestDemo obj=new TestDemo();
        TestDemo2 obj1= new TestDemo2();
        obj.show(5);
        obj1.show("helloworld");
    }
}
class TestDemo{
    public void show(int i){
        
        System.out.println(i*2);
    }  
}
class TestDemo2{
    public void show(String S){
        System.out.println(S);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `short N`, in `public void show(short N)` from `test Demo` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

try to cast the int first.

```
obj.show((short)5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number 5 is treated by default as integer which is passed to method with short argument.

```
obj.show((short)5);
```

Also for future reference, java errors as well as exceptions are very detailed, giving you the exact line number where the issue occurred. That should help you identify the code segment where the issue is.

Comment: Bit of an odd 'for future reference' you tossed in there - the lack of cast means this is a compile time error. Stack traces are irrelevant to this question. You might as well throw in some advice about fly fishing ;)

Comment: Nevertheless, the compiler error will identify the line number.